# Unrecognized selector when using MyAppDelegate

Tags: objective-c

I have followed the instructions (I believe) [Use your app delegate to share info between objects](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/66286-use-your-app-delegate-to-share-info-between-objects.html)

but I keep getting the following errors:

> [AppDelegate setBackgroundAudio:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x10d822400
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate
>   setBackgroundAudio:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x10d822400'

**MyAppDelegate.h**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject{
    AVAudioPlayer *backgroundAudio;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *backgroundAudio;

@end
```

**MyAppDelegate.m**

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate
@synthesize backgroundAudio;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
MyAppDelegate *app_delegate = (MyAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

backgroundAudioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"];

backgroundAudioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundAudioPath];
app_delegate.backgroundAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundAudioURL error:Nil];

[app_delegate.backgroundAudio setDelegate:self];
[app_delegate.backgroundAudio setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[app_delegate.backgroundAudio prepareToPlay];

if (app_delegate.backgroundAudio != nil){
    [app_delegate.backgroundAudio stop];
    [app_delegate.backgroundAudio setCurrentTime:0];
    [app_delegate.backgroundAudio play];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made `MyAppDelegate` a subclass of `NSObject`, so it's in no way (other than it's name) your app delegate.

When you get your real app delegate and cast it as `MyAppDelegate`, you've now got an object that you've told the compiler implements backgroundAudio, but it doesn't.  The quick remedy is to redeclare `MyAppDelegate` as a subclass of `UIResponder`, implementing the `<UIApplicationDelegate>` protocol.

Be sure to tell your app main about it, like this:

```
// main.m
// all the usual stuff from your main.m

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MyAppDelegate class]));
```